# Javascript code saving data to 2d array throws undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web-scraping

I'm writing a script that takes values from a html table, indexes them in aray and then assign every value to a  tag in a form.**Codepen** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVLKyB

My problem is that after taking all specified values from array I get 
[image]

Code responsible for indexing values from table look like this:

```
   function size_index(){
        var table = document.getElementsByClassName("product_table_cus");
        var index= [[],[]];
        var i_index = 0;
        var iter = 0; //index of first dim of array
        var len = table[0].rows.length;
        console.log("Len:"+len);
        while(i_index<len) {
           //iterate trough rows




               console.log("second for, iter:"+ i_index);
               var col_inner = table[0].rows[i_index].cells[0].innerHTML; //size param
               var col_param = table[0].rows[i_index].cells[1].innerHTML;//size value
               var col_size = col_inner.substr(col_inner.indexOf(' ')+1);
                console.log("Rozmiar:"+ col_size+"  Wartość:"+col_param);
        //       index[1][0].push("col_size");
          //     index[i_index][1].push(col_param);
                if(col_inner.search("Rozmiar")!==-1)
                {
                  console.log("Inner wtf:"+col_inner+"Ite:"+iter);
                  index[iter].push(col_inner,col_param);
                  console.log("Index+:"+index[iter]);
                  console.log("Ind:"+col_inner+"Val:"+col_param);
                }
                else if(col_inner.search("Rozmiar")==-1){

                }
                iter++;



          //     col_param=0;
        //       col_size=0;
               //iterate through columns
               //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop


           //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
           i_index++;

         }
         return index;
      }
```

Comment: _“Has array iterator gone too far?”_ — isn’t that something the console would be able to tell you?

Comment: It tells me that it didn't

Comment: `index` is an array of length 2. You are accessing with another variable, `iter` which is incremented each time thought a loop that will happen `table[0].rows.length` times. So any time `table[0].rows.length` is greater than 2 you will get an error because you will be trying to index past the end of the array.

Comment: @WinithePooh _Yes, it tells you that it did._ `iter` is evidently shown as `2`. The `index` array doesn’t have an index `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it in the console log:

This line of code

`console.log("Inner wtf:"+col_inner+"Ite:"+iter);`

Produces this output

> ```
> Inner wtf:Rozmiar XXLIte:2
> ```

Your `index` variable has exactly two values in it.
So of course, if `iter` is a value greater than one, this line will cause an error:

`index[iter].push(col_inner,col_param);`

There are two elements in index, so `index[2]` will return `undefined`.

---

Your underlying problem is that `[[][]]` is not a two dimensional array. It is an array containing two arrays.

A safer way to do this is:

```
var index= [];
```

Then, to add an element:

```
index[iter] = index[iter] || [];
index[iter].push(...);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!